# Will electrolysis of molten sodium hypochlorite work

Tags: electrolysis

I have an anhydrous mixture of sodium hypochlorite and sodium chlorate that was obtained by boiling bleach. If I were to melt this mixture and perform electrolysis on it, would sodium metal be produced, or would it immediately react with one of the chemicals in the mixture?

Comment: Wow, you'd sooner make it from salty soup. That idea is wrong on many levels.

Comment: "The anhydrous compound is unstable and may decompose explosively."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. [Sodium hypochlorite decomposes at 101°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_hypochlorite).

Answer (score 1):

Boiling down Chlorine Bleach composed of sodium hypochlorite (and sodium chloride owing to its industrial creation from the action of chlorine on NaOH) results in mostly just NaCl and a touch of NaClO3.

It is the first step in a generally inefficient path to chlorate (see, for example, [discussion here](https://www.thoughtco.com/potassium-chlorate-bleach-and-salt-substitute-608265)).

Sodium chlorate liberates upon heating oxygen gas ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chlorate)) leaving Sodium chloride.

So, expect the same products associated with the electrolysis of Sodium chloride. In particular: Sodium metal and chlorine gas can be obtained with the electrolysis of molten sodium chloride, while the electrolysis of aqueous sodium chloride yields hydrogen and chlorine, with aqueous sodium hydroxide remaining in solution. Source, see this [educational reference](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introchem/chapter/electrolysis-of-sodium-chloride/).